# How to pass CloudFormation parameter as Type: Number?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a Budget in an AWS account by deploying the following AWS CloudFormation Template (with Azure DevOps):

```yaml
Parameters:
  EmailRecipients:
    Type: String
    Description: Name of the Email Recipient
  BudgetAmount:
    Type: Number
    Default: 500
    Description: Budget Amount
  AmountThreshold:
    Type: Number
    Default: 80
    Description: Budget Threshold

Resources:
  BudgetExample:
    Type: "AWS::Budgets::Budget"
    Properties:
      Budget:
        BudgetLimit:
          Amount: !Sub ${BudgetAmount}
          Unit: USD
        TimeUnit: MONTHLY
        BudgetType: COST
      NotificationsWithSubscribers:
        - Notification:
            NotificationType: ACTUAL
            ComparisonOperator: GREATER_THAN
            Threshold: !Sub ${AmountThreshold}
          Subscribers:
            - SubscriptionType: EMAIL
              Address: !Sub ${EmailRecipients}
```

But get the following error:

```
##[error]MultipleValidationErrors: There were 2 validation errors:
* InvalidParameterType: Expected params.Parameters[1].ParameterValue to be a string
* InvalidParameterType: Expected params.Parameters[2].ParameterValue to be a string
```

I have tried changing the `Type` from `Number` to `String` but with the same error.
Also tried resolving the parameter by the other intrinsic function `!Ref` without luck.
This is how I set the parameters for the CloudFormation template from a azure-pipelines.yml file:

```yaml
variables:
  email_recipients: "example@gmail.com"
  budget_amount: 100
  amount_threshold: 80
```

And this is how they get passed them to template:

```yaml
            - task: CloudFormationCreateOrUpdateStack@1
              displayName: budgets
              inputs:
                awsCredentials: ${{parameters.aws_credentials}}
                regionName: ${{parameters.aws_region}}
                stackName: ${{parameters.stack_name}}
                templateSource: 'file'
                templateFile: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/${{parameters.project_name}}-templates/budgets.yml
                templateParametersSource: "inline"
                templateParameters: |
                  - ParameterKey: EmailRecipients
                    ParameterValue: ${{parameters.email_recipients}}
                  - ParameterKey: BudgetAmount
                    ParameterValue: ${{parameters.budget_amount}}
                  - ParameterKey: AmountThreshold
                    ParameterValue: ${{parameters.amount_threshold}}
                useChangeSet: true
                changeSetName: 'role-changeset'
                captureStackOutputs: asVariables
                captureAsSecuredVars: false
```

Comment: How do you set the parameters when you want to deploy your template?

Comment: Thanks, @Marcin , I have an azure-pipelines.yml file where I pass down the parameters. I tried both setting them as strings and as integers. Keep getting the same `InvalidParameterType` error though. Any thoughts ?

Comment: Does using `!Ref` instead of `!Sub` solve the issue as in the answer given?

Comment: @Marcin Unfortunately not, I gave it a shot.

Comment: I though so :-( The error is not about Ref or Sub. I think its something to do with how the arguments are passed to the template.

Comment: I think you are right. Maybe I need to look into the Azure Pipelines YAML reference a bit more ? See if there is a way to enforce type to be number or so.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with azure pipelines, so can't suggest what could be the cause.

Comment: @Marcin fair enough, but you helped me to realize that the issue is at least on the Azure Pipeline side. I much appreciate it.

Comment: Could you have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63959555/assigning-aws-cloudformation-output-variables-in-azure-devops-pipelines). They pass the `templateParameters` as  enitre strings blocks using `|` in yaml.

Comment: Thanks, @Marcin . I also created a new question to better reflect that my issue is actually on the Azure side: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66061022/pass-azure-pipeline-variable-to-aws-cloudformation-template-as-parameter-with-ty . In your example, I think they only pass string parameters, maybe I am missing something ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#parameters-section-structure-properties)

`Number`:

> An integer or float. AWS CloudFormation validates the parameter value as a number; however, when you use the parameter elsewhere in your template (for example, by using the Ref intrinsic function), the parameter value becomes a string.

```yaml
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: >-
    Deploy an instance of wallaby api to your AWS Organization.
Parameters:
  EmailRecipients:
    Type: String
    Description: Name of the Email Recipient
  BudgetAmount:
    Type: Number
    Default: 500
    Description: Budget Amount
  AmountThreshold:
    Type: Number
    Default: 80
    Description: Budget Threshold

Resources:
  BudgetExample:
    Type: "AWS::Budgets::Budget"
    Properties:
      Budget:
        BudgetLimit:
          Amount: !Ref BudgetAmount
          Unit: USD
        TimeUnit: MONTHLY
        BudgetType: COST
      NotificationsWithSubscribers:
        - Notification:
            NotificationType: ACTUAL
            ComparisonOperator: GREATER_THAN
            Threshold: !Ref AmountThreshold
          Subscribers:
            - SubscriptionType: EMAIL
              Address: !Ref EmailRecipients
```

[cfn-lint](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint) check

```sh
$ cfn-lint cfn.yml
$ echo $?
0
```

UPDATE:

As the original post got updated. User created another post [Pass Azure pipeline variable to AWS Cloudformation template as parameter with type: Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66061022/pass-azure-pipeline-variable-to-aws-cloudformation-template-as-parameter-with-ty)

Comment: Could you please revisit the answer. It is not about use of Ref or Sub.

Comment: @Marcin sure seems like the question got updated. I answered it based on the initial facts being shared in the OP regarding passing the number as it is saying right now too. Plus it is not yet accepted as the answer. I can check  `Azure Pipeline Yaml` syntax and update. Like you I too am not acquainted with `Azure Pipeline Yaml`.

Comment: No problem. Just wanted to let you know as you may better idea about azure that I have:-)

Comment: @Marcin really appreciated the mention.  I am learning from your answers here.  As I mentioned in my earlier comment, I too am like you in the case of  `Azure` :) Have a good day!!